# JavaScript Node.contains() function does not check inner children elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am making a React app, where I have made a custom DatePicker component. I want it to be hidden if outside click happened (as I did with other components, such as Select Dropdown). Long story short I wrote a custom hook:

```
export default (ref, visible, setVisible) => {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        let handleClick;

        if (visible) {
            handleClick = (e) => {
                if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
                    setVisible((prevVisible) => !prevVisible);
                }
            };

            document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
        }

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
        };
    }, [visible]);
};
```

The problem is when I am using it with Select component which has its items as a direct children everything works fine, but with DatePicker it closes after date selection. That is happening because the day element itself is inner child for the REF of my calendar container. The structure is something like this:

```
<div class="picker">
    * A <p> tag here for triggering the visibility state *
    <div className="calendar" ref={calendar}>
        <div className="month">
            <div className="week">
                <div className="day">
                    * day number *
                </div>
                * More days *
            </div>
            * More weeks *
        </div>
        * Second month *
    </div>
</div>
```

In MDN docs I read that ref.current.contains should run through all the children elements, but it somehow check only divs with "MONTH" class, i.e. only direct children. Has anyone faced the same problem? I would have appreciated any help! Thanks!

P.S here is the image of my DOM tree after the DatePicker component was opened:

[image]

Comment: What element is the ref being passed to?

Comment: @evolutionxbox the calendar element that contains inside two month blocks (because I made the date-range-picker) and control buttons (not present in the example above).
P.S. checkout the pseudo jsx/html markup code sample above, with ref prop passed to a div with calendar className

Comment: Any element clicked inside `.calendar` will result in `ref.current.contains(e.target)` being `true`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Suddenly, that is not the case. Somehow when I click on `.month` (because I have paddings) or on `.week` the `console.log(ref.current.contains(e.target))` returns `true`, but when I click on `.day`,that are placed inside of the `.week` container, I somehow get `false` on the same `console.log(ref.current.contains(e.target))`

Comment: Then `.week` is not a descendant of `.calendar`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox It is, the `.month` is the direct child of the `.calendar` and the `.week` is the child of `.month` (not direct, because it covered with `div` with no class for the sake of flexbox container, but it is in there)

Comment: If that were true at the time of the render then `.contains` would be true. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains

Comment: @evolutionxbox I am not sure if I am allowed to do this here, but here is the link to the screenshot of my DOM tree after the DatePicker component was opened https://disk.yandex.ru/d/XDb5yohXaA7kJg

Comment: May you put the actual image link into the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was as simple as possible: I was generating the key prop for each array element using `Math.random()`, don't do it :)

Replacing it with simple array index fixed the bug.

P.S. Somehow the dynamic generation of key in order to not to use the array index, was blocking the process of getting parentNode property for the array element. It was returning `null`, although element had like 15 parent nodes before the `#document` root